# Is it possible to make UIImagePickerController.cameraOverlay UIView stay behind camera controls?

Tags: ios, camera, overlay, uiimagepickercontroller

I have a situation that I need to show to user the Camera Capture with a overlay. The overlay it's only a rect marking a area to capture, with a shadow in outside bounds.

So, I would like to present this overlay behind the camera controls. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [Apple's documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIImagePickerController_Class/UIImagePickerController/UIImagePickerController.html), there is no way to have your overlay view show behind the built-in camera controls.

They recommend sizing and positioning the overlay view so that it doesn't interfere with the camera controls or hiding the built-in camera controls and building your own in a sub view.